# Android SDK is not found by flutter

Tags: software-installation, android, android-sdk, sdk

i have installed android studio by unzipping the zip file from the official site and running `sudo ./studio.sh`.
so, it was installed in **/root** directory.
but when i installed flutter as recommended in the official site, it said that android sdk is not found along with android studio.

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.6.0, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set $ANDROID_HOME to that location.
[✗] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.26.1)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

after that, i tried googling for some answers and i did found'em which were all like this:
adding $ANDROID_HOME to **home/.bashrc** or **home/.bashrc_profile** or in my case, to **home/.zshrc**, following the execution of the command ***source /.the_file*** 

BUT, that didn't work, why !!? i don't know!

here is my configuration for environment var

```
export PATH=/home/joe-inz/Flutter/flutterSDK/flutter/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/root/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools/:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

to confirm:

```
/home/joe-inz/Flutter/flutterSDK/flutter/bin /home/joe-inz/Flutter/flutterSDK/flutter/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/games /usr/local/games /snap/bin /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin /root/Android/Sdk/tools /root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/ /root/Android/Sdk /home/joe-inz/.config/composer/vendor/bin /home/joe-inz/.config/composer/vendor/bin /root/Android/Sdk/tools /root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/ /root/Android/Sdk /home/joe-inz/.config/composer/vendor/bin
```

ps: the reason for **$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT** because I read is some issue in GitHub that $ANDROID_HOME is deprecated !!!!, although with $ANDROID_HOME it didn't work.
Please don't mark it as duplicate because I've tried the previous solutions an none of them worked!
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You do not install studio in `/root` it should be in `/home/$USER` or `/opt` please move it to `/home/$USER` (best location IMO)  and change the ownership to yours...

Comment: it was installed by default in /root ... can you tell me how to change location ?

Comment: do `sudo cp -R /root/android-studio ~/ && sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/android-studio`, NOTE: Make sure the name of the android studio folder is correct as it is in your system, I assume it is called `android-studio` as in mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to my problem (other parties could find the Android SDK) is to make sure Android Studio is installed in home directory or where other parties could find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official installation [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/install):

Linux

To install Android Studio on Linux, proceed as follows:

1. Unpack the .zip file you downloaded to an appropriate location for your applications, such as within `/usr/local/` for your user profile, or `/opt/` for shared users.
2. To launch Android Studio, open a terminal, navigate to the `android-studio/bin/` directory, and execute `studio.sh`.
3. Select whether you want to import previous Android Studio settings or not, then click OK.
4. The Android Studio Setup Wizard guides you though the rest of the setup, which includes downloading Android SDK components that are required for development.

Now move the folders to your `/home/$USER` directory as I feel this gives you less trouble (IMO) and then delete it:

```
sudo cp -R /root/android-studio ~/ && sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/android-studio && sudo rm -rf /root/android-studio
```

**NOTE:** Make sure the name of the android studio folder is correct as it is in your system, I assume it is called **android-studio** as in mine

Comment: thank you for your help, I've fixed it by running the installer again from the created entry and installing android studio in /home directory.